# Problems when saving an argument to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have some code which basically just takes the arg from a command and compares it in an if statement with some text. I don't know why but I keep getting this error when it tries to save the arg to a variable:

```
Ignoring exception in command raceinfo:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DiscordMMO\Scripts\Character_Creator.py", line 66, in some_crazy_function_name
    raceInfo = ctx.arg
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'arg'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'arg'
```

Here's the snippet of code:

```
@bot.command(name="raceinfo")
async def some_crazy_function_name(ctx, arg):
        raceInfo = ctx.arg
        if raceInfo == "Human" or "human":
```

Comment: Can you try adding the code that you currently have? This would make it a lot easier for use to help you.

Comment: could you please add an actual piece of code?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the code, added it on now

Comment: Well, the error is pretty self-explanatory. ``ctx`` has no element ``arg`` inside.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'arg'` seems like it should be pretty self-explanatory for you and completely opaque to everyone else who does not know anything about the relevant objects.

Comment: But it does, i used the command /raceinfo human and it gave me that error

Comment: @Tazgirl what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element named `arg` in `ctx`. If you want to store the `arg` in the variable: `raceInfo`, just do `raceInfo = arg`. Or, instead of having `arg` as the parameter, just put it like such:

```py
@bot.command(name="raceinfo")
async def some_crazy_function_name(ctx, raceInfo):
    if raceInfo == "Human" or raceInfo == "human":
        print(raceInfo)  # Add whatever code you would like
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought i had to specify it with ctx. I'm new to working with arguments

Comment: @Tazgirl No problem! Everyone starts out with something.

Comment: You're top 2 percent this year. That isn't bad. I'm not that good.

Comment: Sorry. I have seen people gaining reputation fast on SO a couple of times...

Comment: Does that mean I'm doing something wrong? I'm afraid I'm doing something against SO policies because I'm gaining reputation fast now.

Comment: @Tazgirl Hey, if I helped, do you think you can give an upvote and an accept? Thanks!

Comment: Will do, it wouldn't let me because the question has to be up for a certain amount of time to accept the answer

Comment: Okay, no problem!